# NServiceBus - Class implementing IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops is not invoked when using Castle.Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus

I'm currently using NServiceBus 4.6.1 using Castle.Windsor as the IoC container. In general it's working fine, however I've recently added a class which implements `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` and this class is never being invoked. I suspect the issue is a conflict between my Castle.Windsor installers and how NServiceBus scans the assemblies to find configuration classes etc.

I'm using the standard NServiceBus Host in this example. I am using a Castle.Windsor installer which registers all components 'WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()' as I do not want to individually register every component I use. I'm also using the Azure Service Bus as a transport mechanism but I don't think this is part of the problem.

Note that I've tried removing Castle.Windsor from the equation and my startup code is invoked (but of course the handlers fail as the dependencies are not injected). I'd like to get both to run at the same time but I can't seem to figure out the right way to configure everything.

I've stripped things right back and still hit the problem, my code is as follows:

```
public class NServiceBusEndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server,
    UsingTransport<AzureServiceBus>,
    IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        Configure.With().CastleWindsorBuilder(container);
        container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
        //I've tried running the installers before the Configure.With() line above, with no change in behaviour
    }
}

public class DefaultInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
            .Pick()
            .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}

public class Startup : IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bus Started"); //this is never called
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bus Stopped");
    }
}
```

Relevant NuGet package used:

- NServiceBus 4.6.1
- NServiceBus.Interfaces 4.6.1
- NServiceBus.Host 4.6.1
- NServiceBus.CastleWindsor 4.6.1
- NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureServiceBus 5.3.0
- Castle.Windsor 3.2.1
- Castle.Core 3.3.0

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve what I want? Or even an alternative way of configuring NServiceBus and Castle.Windsor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a fix or a workaround, but I've managed to resolve the problem.

In my case, the NServiceBus host project (the code in my question) only contained NServiceBus related code (configuration, message handlers, etc). All of the dependencies that I relied on Castle.Windsor to resolve were located in other assemblies/namespaces. So I modified my Castle.Windsor installer to only register classes in those assemblies (and leave the host assembly untouched), and that solved the issue. Castle.Windsor registered types in my referenced assemblies and NServiceBus handled the host assembly - my startup code was called as I wanted, and the message handlers all worked as before.

My new Castle.Windsor installer is as follows:

```
public class DefaultInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyReferencedAssembly")
                .Pick()
                .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

I'd still be interested to know if anyone has a better way, but for now: problem solved.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved the issue, although I think it is worth raising a bug for it in https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/new

Comment: @JohnSimons I've done as you recommended - the issue is here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2306

Answer (score 0):

The reason your implementation is not called is that `WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()` will NOT register `EndpointConfig` as a implementation of `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops`. It will try to register it as an implementation of the non existent interface `IEndpointConfig`, nothing else.

That being said you should never register types NServiceBus picks up by itself anyway. Let NServiceBus handle that.

For details, check out my comment on https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.CastleWindsor/issues/2.